# Business Data Preparation for Reporting and BI

Tags: reporting, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am doing some research about what the best possible state that data should be in so that reporting and BI analytics perform well but can be produced by business users from a set of various data collections which align with a business data glossary that I have worked through.

1. We have not chosen a specific BI tool but have been playing around with Power BI and Sisense
2. We have not decided on a data store technology to use for reporting purposes

**Origin Data**

Our business application that the data will originate from has a normalised SQL relational database. There are quite a few tables and joins to consider which work fine from an application perspective but I have recommended supplying the output of those queries as a flat denormalised set of data to increase redundancy and remove the joins entirely.

**Business Data Glossary**

As we go through defining the business data glossary, the number of columns increases but I do not anticipate there being any more than 100 columns per row as a complete reporting set of data. I wanted to ensure that each row of data is at a transactional depth (level 0) and that the roll up through the data would be done through aggregations by distinct key values and dimensional taxonomy.

**Architecture**

I want some advice around what a modern architecture looks like and what works for business users rather than users who are comfortable with SQL queries and a myriad of joins on a physical data model.

I read an article about setting up data flows for Power BI which looked like they type of thing I want to do from a data availability perspective but it doesn't advice on how the data should be stored and what type of database to use.

**Data Sets**

The data we have that needs to be reported on are transactions where level 0 is trade positions (individual transactions from either a local or counterparty entity), level 1 is reconciliations (relating local and counterparty entities and trade linking identifier) and level 2 would be where it can be rolled up by taxonomy like asset type or status.

The current data set size would be a snapshot of positions every business day so, its duplicated every day with a snapshot date applied. The reports would be able to move across dates and show changes over time.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated on how to tackle reporting and BI in 2020. Oooh, one last thing, there is the possibility that we won't be allowed to process this type of data in the public cloud, we have our own infrastructure which is on private cloud so, that might need to be a consideration. Thanks

Comment: What is total size of your DB? As you want to get rid of JOINs I guess it is rather big, but for 10Gb, 100Gb and many TBs solutions may be are quote different. Is near real-time reporting desired?

On-premise PowerBI is not cheap for sure. If you're looking for primarily table-based reporting (pivot tables) niche solutions may play better.

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko thank you for your input - the reason for the joins is a legacy decision a long time ago to always bow to client data needs. Currently, there is an SQL table per client because each client had very separate requirements even though processing the same sort of data. Nowadays, semi-structured with transformations would have been more desirable but until we change the application design, joins will be needed to force all client data into same size and shape. The total volume of data in the last 2 years is around 100GB, not crazy amount but exponentially growing